# why does cd seem to effect wildcard globbing over ls?

Tags: bash, quoting

The following script does not work:

```
set -x

cd "${HOME}/${PROJECT}"                               
echo "create specified jars list"                                      
cat /dev/null > jar-versions                                    
for config in $(ls *.clj); do      
  echo $config                                                         
  <some pile of java>
done
```

it errors out with the following:

```
+ cd /home/pat/
+ echo 'create specified jars list'
create specified jars list
+ cat /dev/null
++ ls '*.clj'
ls: cannot access *.clj: No such file or directory
```

the error appears to be that there is some funky quoting going on with the ls in the for loop.  I don't know why that happens.  The following code works as expected:

```
set -x

#cd "${HOME}/${PROJECT}"                               
echo "create specified jars list"                                      
cat /dev/null > jar-versions                                                                              
for config in $(ls *.clj); do
  echo $config                                                         
  <some pile of java>
done
```

The only difference is that I've commented out the cd call.  I have a workaround but I'm flummoxed about why the execution of cd is mucking with the quoting of the wildcard.

I'm running on ubuntu 14.02 and bash GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release

**EDIT** as requested I have explained where the 'cat /dev/null' came from (good catch @123) and below is the output of 'set -x' of the working script.

```
+ echo 'create specified jars list'
create specified jars list
+ cat /dev/null
++ ls config.clj tinyconfig.clj
+ for config in '$(ls *.clj)'
+ echo config.clj
config.clj
+ for config in '$(ls *.clj)'
+ echo tinyconfig.clj
tinyconfig.clj
```

Comment: Why not `for config in *.clj` instead?

Comment: tried that and got the same result:  for config in '*.cl'

Comment: Or use the full path in the loop: `$HOME/$PROJECT/*.clj`.

Comment: Your reply shows single quotes around `*.cl(j)`; try without.

Comment: @Evert that's the issue, I don't know why the single quotes are showing up when I am executing cd.  In the functional second example, the only difference is that I've commented out the cd.

Comment: Is $HOME really `/home/`, and `$PROJECT` `pat`? On most systems (like Ubuntu here), $HOME would be `/home/pat/`, which indicates `$PROJECT` is not set or empty. Which means your first script uses the incorrect directory. Your second script uses the directory you're in, which is probably the correct directory. Double check `$PROJECT`.

Comment: @Evert good eye!  however, you'll notice the trailing backslash after 'pat'.  What's happening there is that `$PROJECT` isn't set in my dev environment so its resolving to empty string.

I removed `$PROJECT` and the error remained the same.

Comment: It's `for config in *.clj ; do ... done`. And then access it as "$config" in the loop with double quotes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I attempted:  `cat jar-versions-test 
set -x

cd ${HOME}
echo "create specified jars list"
cat /dev/null > jar-versions
for config in $(ls *.clj); do
  echo "$config"
done
`  but executing it not catting it out and got the same error.  is that the syntax you wanted me to use?

Comment: Where has that `cat /dev/null` come from ?Also can you show output for -x on the working script

Comment: @123 the `cat /dev/null` was a copy paste error.  I was removing white space and accidentally removed a line.  I willl put it back.  And adding the -x of the working script

Comment: @coffeepac Yep, whatever directory the cd is taking you to does not contain your .clj files. As for the quoting, if the glob doesn't expand then it does a normal search for the filename which you will see is always single quoted in `-x` output(if it contains a special character). You could try a couple of things. `echo "${HOME}/${PROJECT}"`, `echo "${HOME}/${PROJECT}"/*`, `echo "$PWD"` and post the output of them please.

Comment: @123 right, this works in production where $PROJECT is set correctly.  I guess I would have expected the ls to return an empty list and the loop wouldn't get evaluated at all.  Thanks for your help!  I won't be providing the information you asked for as you've already pointed out the problem.

Comment: @coffeepac oki doke, glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

Failed to notice the an env var was not set in my local environment.  Works when env var is set.